# What's wrong with this url?

Tags: python, django

I have a root urls.py and an app urls.py. In my root I have this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', include('realestate.properties.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In my app urls I have the following

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('realestate.properties.views',
    url(r'^$', 'property_list', {'template_name': 'properties/property_list.html'}, name='property_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'property_detail', { 'template': 'property_detail.html' }, name='property_details'),
)
```

now in my template I have a link to the details view, which looks like this:

```
{% url property_details property.slug %}
```

Everytime I render this page i get the error:

***Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'property_details' with arguments '(u'111-front-st',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.***

No matter what I do, I get that error. I tried capturing just the id and nothing is working, i am not sure why, I have used url's many times before so I am really confused if I am missing something obvious. Any see anything wrong here?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to drop the `$` from your urlconf, where you include the app's urls. Probably you can remove the `^` too.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include('realestate.properties.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

> Note that the regular expressions in
>   this example don't have a $
>   (end-of-string match character) but do
>   include a trailing slash. Whenever
>   Django encounters include(), it chops
>   off whatever part of the URL matched
>   up to that point and sends the
>   remaining string to the included
>   URLconf for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'realestate.properties.views.property_list'),
    (r'^properties/', include('realestate.properties.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Otherwise (like sugested by [Reiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556536/reiner-gerecke)s post) you will make the first regular expression a "catch all" and /admin will never match.

You can also place the admin regular expression before your "catch all" re, but what happens if you have a slug like 'admin'? That is why I would advice against a url scheme with `/<slug>/` at the first level. Instead, use `/<object-type>/<slug>/`, that will make room for other things in the future.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, this worked but I don't agree with this. I would rather use my root urls to include app urls and keep app-related patterns out of the root. I have always included my app urls in other projects without any problems with other urls being mapped. I did however forget to remove the $ in my match all for including base urls and that worked out fine.